# Cannot migrate to Android 13

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-13, android-tiramisu

I'm trying to migrate my app to Android 13, but I can't manage to do so. I have the following contents in by main module gradle build file:

```
android {
    // Android Build Settings
    compileSdk 33
    buildToolsVersion "33.0.0"
    ndkVersion "25.0.8528842"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        ...
    }

    ...
```

And I'm using version 7.2.1 of AGP:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        // Build tools
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21'

        ...
    }
}
```

Those are the steps [required by Google](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/setup-sdk), but when I sync the project something is completely wrong. For example, all the manifest entries are marked as `Unknown attribute android:...`. I've tried using the latest canary version "Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 6", downloaded the latest versions of the Android's SDK "Android TiramisuPrivacySandbox Preview" (`TiramisuPrivacySandbox`), "Android Tiramisu (Tiramisu)" (`33`) and "Android Tiramisu Preview" (`Tiramisu`). I've also checked that I have downloaded "Android SDK Build Tools 33", cleaned and rebuilt the project, cleaned and restarted Android Studio.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `buildToolsVersion` doesn't belong there.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It's the place specified by Google: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools

Comment: You might still try removing it, to see if it helps. Usually, nowadays, the build tools version is inferred from other information.

Comment: Removing `buildToolsVersion` sadly doesn't fix anything. Neither does `ndkVersion`, or removing both. It's important to say that the app compiles and runs correctly, but the Android Studio's inspector turns crazy. @CommonsWare

Comment: I'm in the same boat in and it's driving me mad. Did you make any progress?

Comment: @Sakiboy now that Android 13 is released officially everything is working fine for me. Try to update everything to the latest version.